# Why is there discrepancy between data shown by Greylog and Grafana?

Tags: logging, prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator, graylog

I think I have a pretty broad question, but I am clearly missing a huge chunk of knowledge here.

Greylog and Grafana (Prometheus -> Actuator) should be showing the same data but actually show something completely different.

My Greylog gathers data from Kafka which has it from Fluentid which receives logs from Kubernetes' pods. Greylog shows me a lot of errors in the logs.

Grafana gathers data from Prometheus which has the data from Spring Actuator. It shows no errors at all whatsoever.

Greylog example:

[image]

Grafana example:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is data provided by actuator (Grafana) plainly wrong? I know that Greylog has the right data and the only difference that I am aware of between the two is that data is persistent in Greylog and in Prometheus (Grafana)... only if I explicitly set it to be so?

Answer (score 0):

My first experienced guess is that Grafana is polling Elastic directly, which is in UTC and your browser isn’t - so the results are both correct for different time zones.  I have definitely made that mistake enough times myself.